# AMD Gpu Memory dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, gpu, amd-processor

I'm writing an C++ dll for using in a C# application.
The dll will check the total GPU memory and the usage of the GPU memory.

Now I have created three methods. The first one does initialize GLew and other OpeGl stuff. The second will read the total memory of the GPU. And the last one will read the GPU usage.

The inialize and the total memory methods does work but with the last one I get some problems. When I call the methode it stops and when I debug it I can set a breakpoint on the delete[] ids; line without any problem. But it does not return anythin on the return available line (it does not get there). When I remove the delte[] ids line I get an error:
'Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'nCurAvailMemoryInKB' was corrupted.'. Do I something wrong to read the usage of the GPU memory?

```
__declspec(dllexport) float getAvailableMemory()
{
    int available = -1;

    if (wglGetGPUIDsAMD && wglGetGPUInfoAMD)
    {
        UINT n = wglGetGPUIDsAMD(0, 0);
        UINT *  ids = new UINT[n];
        wglGetGPUIDsAMD(n, ids);

        GLint nCurAvailMemoryInKB = 0;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,
            &nCurAvailMemoryInKB);

        available = nCurAvailMemoryInKB;

        delete[] ids;
    }

    return available;
}
```

I created a test caller for the Dll in C#:
class Program {

```
[DllImport("AmdLib.dll")]
public static extern bool init();
[DllImport("AmdLib.dll")]
public static extern int getTotalMemory();
[DllImport("AmdLib.dll")]
public static extern float getAvailableMemory();

static void Main(string[] args) {
  init();
  Console.WriteLine("Total");
  Console.WriteLine(getTotalMemory());
  Console.WriteLine("Available");
  Console.WriteLine(getAvailableMemory());
}
```

}

And the full C++ DLL source does looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    static HGLRC ctx = NULL;

    __declspec(dllexport) bool init()
    {
        HWND hwnd = NULL;

        HINSTANCE hinstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        WNDCLASSA window_class;
        window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_GLOBALCLASS;
        window_class.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
        window_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
        window_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
        window_class.hInstance = hinstance;
        window_class.hIcon = NULL;
        window_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        window_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        window_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        window_class.lpszClassName = "test_class";

        ATOM atom = RegisterClassA(&window_class);
        hwnd = CreateWindowA("test_class", "htest", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL, hinstance, NULL);

        if (hwnd == NULL) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            return false;
        }

        HDC hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

        if (hDC == NULL) {
            return false;
        }

        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR const pfd =
        {
            sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
            1,
            PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
            0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
            0,
            0, 0, 0
        };
        int pixel_format = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
        SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixel_format, &pfd);
        ctx = wglCreateContext(hDC);

        if (ctx) {
            if (!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, ctx)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);

        GLenum glew = glewInit();

        return true;
    }

    static void check_gl_error()
    {
        GLenum error = glGetError();

        assert(error == GL_NO_ERROR);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) int getTotalMemory()
    {
        if (wglGetGPUIDsAMD && wglGetGPUInfoAMD)
        {
            UINT n = wglGetGPUIDsAMD(0, 0);
            UINT *  ids = new UINT[n];
            UINT    total_mem_mb = 0;
            wglGetGPUIDsAMD(n, ids);

            wglGetGPUInfoAMD(ids[0], WGL_GPU_RAM_AMD, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, sizeof(UINT), &total_mem_mb);

            delete[] ids;

            return total_mem_mb;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) float getAvailableMemory()
    {
        int available = -1;

        if (wglGetGPUIDsAMD && wglGetGPUInfoAMD)
        {
            UINT n = wglGetGPUIDsAMD(0, 0);
            UINT *  ids = new UINT[n];
            wglGetGPUIDsAMD(n, ids);

            GLint nCurAvailMemoryInKB = 0;
            glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI,
                &nCurAvailMemoryInKB);

            available = nCurAvailMemoryInKB;

            //delete[] ids;
        }

        return available;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check whether wglGetGPUIDsAMD function pointer is initialized correctly, and its type exactly matches the library function.

Comment: wglGetGPUIDsAMD does initialize the pointer correct. When I debug I can see the correct value of nCurAvailMemoryInKB. But when I return it immediatly after glGetIntegerv I got the 'Stack around the variable 'nCurAvailMemoryInKB' was corrupted' error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I would very much like to do this myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have an ATI card to test with, off the top of my head I'd guess the first `wglGetGPUIDsAMD` call returns 0, you allocate a 0-length array (which works) and at the end you try to delete it (which throws). Somewhere in-between you overwrite the memory around that pointer with data (thus corrupting the guards and making VS throw).

Now looking at what you're actually doing with that array, or the knowledge of how many GPUs you have, you never actually use either of them. You can literally delete both calls to `wglGetGPUIDsAMD` and the array allocation/deallocation, and just call `glGetIntegerv`.

Comment: When I call glGetIntegerv without the other code I got a 'Stack around the variable 'nCurAvailMemoryInKB' was corrupted' error.